# Get internet speed of User with GWT

Tags: gwt

I want to get internet download & upload speedof user  in my **GWT** web application,programmatically.

After done much research ,I couldn't find a way to do it in `GWT`.

Is there a way to get `internet speed` of the user in `GWT`?

Comment: You want to check the users internet speed in program?? or want to know your application loading speed ??

Comment: I want to check the users internet speed in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a no straight way to do it in GWT.You can find many ways in Js or [Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/tEFpC/2/)

In the same way,Take one `image` and upload it to server through `RPC`.Note `RPC` `start time` and and the note the time in `RPC end`(first line of onSuccess).By calculating the `elapsed time` with `size of image` ,you may get the upload time.And same for the `download` also.

P.S:  I did'nt try it.Just an idea.

Comment: Only torrent on full speed can show actual internet speed. Downloading single file in single thread will show speed much more slower then real connection. So if we can't start torrents, may be start about 10 or 20 downloads in one moment?

Answer (score -1):

Run your GWT web application and inspect the web page(right click mouse and choose inspect element) Then choose net or network from that then click upload or download and check how much time it took to upload and download file.

Comment: I think PO is asking programmatically.Not using developer tools,if i am not wrong.